# Homebrew's formula is not recognized

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew

I just installed Homebrew in macOS Mojave. When trying:

```
$ brew install --fresh imagemagick --with-perl
```

there appears an output explanatory text about the usage of brew formulas, finishing by:

```
Error: invalid option: --fresh
```

Similarly, `$ brew install imagemagick --with-perl` gives out the forementioned text finishing by: `Error: invalid option: --with-perl`

(On the other hand, `$ brew install imagemagick` works, but there fails the perl interface, so that I wished to install it with the perl option as above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option `--fresh` to the `brew` command. If you want to reinstall a package, you do:

```
brew uninstall PACKAGE
brew install PACKAGE
```

All packages in `homebrew-core` no longer have any options - it was too onerous on the maintainers. Now all packages contain a core, broad set of options and that is what you get.

If you want to see how your **ImageMagick** is configured, use:

```
magick identify -list configure
```

Comment: There's also `brew reinstall PACKAGE` if you want to save a little typing.